# Which method need to be called to get contentKey for FairPlay DRM implementaiton?

Tags: objective-c, drm, fairplay

I have `streamingContentKeyRequestDataForApp` to create SPC message and `getContentKeyAndLeaseExpiryfromKeyServerModuleWithRequest` to get the CKC data. I could get the CKC data.

I'm using `persistentContentKeyFromKeyVendorResponse` method to get the ContentKey. Since I have kept `@{AVAssetResourceLoadingRequestStreamingContentKeyRequestRequiresPersistentKey: @YES}`    this in the options when creating SPC.

The result I'm obtaining is `nil` for the content Key.

Please suggest how to proceed after this.

Thanks a lot for spending your time!

Answer (score 1):

You have to set a correct options value when getting SPC from a loading request:

```
let options =  @{AVAssetResourceLoadingRequestStreamingContentKeyRequestRequiresPersistentKey : @YES};
let serverPlaybackContext = [loadingRequest streamingContentKeyRequestDataForApp:certificate contentIdentifier:contentId options:options error:&error];
```

And then send this data to a DRM server to obtain CKC for offline playback.